# How to pass complex type parameters to a Web Service

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

My Web Service provider provides a WSDL with following part in it.

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dtAcData">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax" />
<s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax" />
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I'm trying to call the service with following code.

```
$dtAcData = array('Name Test');
$param = array(
                'strApp'          =>  'TEST',
                'strCode'   =>  '82',
                'strDelim'      =>  '^',
                'strDate'           =>  $tranDate,
                'strTime'           =>  $tranTime,
                'strNetID'          =>  'test',
                'intRefNum'         =>  $txn_referance_number,
                'intSTNUM'           =>  $intStan,
                'strTranMsg'        =>  '0200',
                'strMerName'        =>  '10.0.01.10',
                'strMCC'            =>  '1111',
                'strToken'          =>  $tranToken,              
                'strIDNum'          =>  '1234598798637',
                'dtAcData'         =>  $dtAcData,
                'R1'                =>  '',
                'R2'                =>  '',
                'R3'                =>  '',
                'R4'                =>  ''
                );

$result = $client->__soapCall("strAcData", $param);
```

I tried to get the expected XML from the provider. My service provider says they do not know the XML format their service expect. I tried associative array with dtAcData. 
$dtAcData = array("Name"=>'Name Test');

But still service returns "System Malfunction".

Service provider says my request does not contain all the data.